# Are bleaching powders effective cleaning agents?

Tags: chemistry, consumer-products, advertising

The claim from the [manufacturer](http://www.vanish.co.uk/products/vanish-oxi-action/vanish-oxi-action-powder):

> Have you seen a stain on your clothes that you can't seem to remove? Don't fear! Vanish Oxi Action Powder contains Oxi Powerlift which removes all types of stains, from the ones you can clearly see to the tougher ones that may be hidden. Vanish Oxi Action Powder is safe to use on both coloured and white clothing.

Does Vanish Oxi Action Powder work?

Comment: Can we generalise this question to all similar products?

Comment: @Sklivvz: How far do you want to go? http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/are-some-laundry-detergents-better-than-others

Comment: [Oxi Action Powder Ingredients](http://www.ocado.com/webshop/product/Vanish-Oxi-Action-Multi-Fabric-Stain-Remover/22076011): Chemical Composition: >30%: Oxygen-Based Bleaching Agents, <5% Nonionic Surfactants, Anionic Surfactants, Enzymes (Proteases, Cellulases), Polymers, Perfume. [Much more details here](http://www.litelines.co.uk/downloads/RC0615.pdf)

Comment: Fwiw it used to be called "nappisan" before cloth nappies went out of fashion and yeah; anecdotally it works. We use about a kilo a month of the stuff.

Comment: so, the product does work as mention by Mark since he used a kilo a month.

Comment: mind=blown. Oxy is just nappisan? But you can still buy nappisan. \*splodes\*

Comment: **Napisan**: 15 - 30 % oxygen based bleaching agents, 5 - 15 % anionic surfactants, < 5 % polycarboxylates. 
Other ingredients: Optical brightener, Perfume

Comment: **Vanish Oxi Crystal White Powder**: >30%: Oxygen-Based Bleaching Agent, <5%: Anionic Surfactants, Non-Ionic Surfactants, Zeolite, Enzymes, Optical Brightener

Comment: They have the same components, however Napisan contains a little bleach to sterilise, whereas Vanish contains more to actually, well, bleach.